# get specific element in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given that I have

```
const countArray = [{count: 97}, {count: 100}, {count: 101}, {count: 102}, {count: 99}, {count: 101}];
```

What could I do to get 97 for example?

here's what Ive tried

```
console.log(Object.values(countArray[0]));
```

this outputs `Array [97]`, but im trying to get just 97.

any help would be appreciated

Note: Ive already looked at similar Stack Overflow posts

Comment: `countArray[0].count` or `Object.values(countArray[0])[0]` if you don't know the key name

Comment: u can try : countArray[0]['count']

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get 97?" Are you asking if there's a way to test if an object in that array has a count of 97?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.values() always returns array. Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

so you can try this
console.log(Object.values(countArray[0])[0]);

and if the key will be same for all the objects then you can try
console.log(countArray[0]['count'] );